# @Nonnull annotation is only marker?

Tags: java, null, guava

I'm new to `@Nonnull` annotation.

I tried to use it and write the following test:

```
public class TestNonull{
    public static void doSmth(@Nonnull Integer integer){}
    public static void main(final String[] arguments){
       doSmth(null);
       doSmth(1);
    }
}
```

I don't see anything in console.

Is it normal?

Comment: Yes for Java they are, but for IDE and Static code analyzer tools such as FindBugs they mean that the value being passed must not be null.

Comment: Also these help you in good documentation of your methods, that the method `doSmth` does not expect input to be `null`

Comment: In my case I need to believe that integer != null inside of the method?  code which invoke *doSmth* must to pass in method valid(!=NULL) value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Nonnull` and `@Nullable` are just markers for your IDE or code analyzers. The javac compiler does not insert any special code for methods annotaded this way.

Comment: In my case I need to believe that integer != null inside of the method? code which invoke doSmth must to pass in method valid(!=NULL) value?

Comment: if you want to make sure an Exception is thrown early you could use guavas [Preconditions.checkNotNull()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull(T)).

Comment: I know it. please answer yes or no to my question

Answer (score 0):

This is only an annotation for your IDE. You should check if the parameter is null before calling the function.

Like that:

```
String capitalize(@NonNull String in) {
        return in.toUpperCase();                // no null check required
    }
    void caller(String s) {
        if (s != null)
            System.out.println(capitalize(s));  // preceding null check is required
    }
```

Check -> [Using null annotations](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_null_annotations.htm)